# Using ThermoPower library in Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'm completely new to Modelica, and so I may not have a complete handle on the subject at this point. I'm trying to use the ThermpoPower 2.1 library, but it doesn't run on the OpenModelica software I have. I did some googling and my search says the library is compatible with Modelica 2.2.

Well I have OpenModelica 1.9 which is the latest version! I assume Modelica and openmodelica are two different softwares. So I looked up Modelica 2.2 to see if I can find it and download it but I was unsuccessful. Can anyone help me here?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Another solution would be to use a different library to model power plants. E.g. ThermoSysPro is compatible both with OpenModelica and Dymola.

Answer (score 3):

OpenModelica partially supports ThermoPower 3.1:
https://test.openmodelica.org/libraries/trend.html

I suggest you get the latest nightly-build which includes ThermoPower 3.1:
https://build.openmodelica.org/omc/builds/windows/nightly-builds/